# How do I get real path as string in Grails

Tags: servlets, grails, embedded-tomcat-8, grails-3.3

Developed project using grails-3.3.1 and generated a Runnable WAR file. When I run using the command:

```
java -jar build/libs/myproject-0.1.war
```

It is returning `null` for the following line:

```
serveltContext.getRealPath("/someSource");
```

But it is working fine when deployed in a Tomcat Container.

Then tried the following way:

```
servletContext.getResource("someSource").getPath();
```

It is returning, but not the one as expected and not what `getRealPath()` returns.
It is returning like this:

```
D:/myprojects/myproject/build/libs/myproject-01.war*/
```

which serves no use for me. Found answers suggesting to use `getResourceAsStream()` but I don't want a resource, I want only `String`.

Comment: Where it is located in your Grails app directory structure?

Comment: Also, what are you trying to achieve by just getting the `String` path instead of the complete file/resource?

Comment: I need to pass that string as a parameter to another resource, which creates a sub-report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to find a solution that worked both locally and when deployed in a container. I ended up using this workaround instead to get the path depending on which environment the code is running in:

```
def path
if (Environment.current == Environment.DEVELOPMENT) {
    path = java.nio.file.FileSystems.default.getPath("someSource").toAbsolutePath().toString()
} else {
    path = ServletContextHolder.servletContext.getRealPath("/someSource")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Grails 4.0.11. Seems like serveltContext.getRealPath is deprecated and returns null. Your solution didn't work either for me, so I decided to go with the following approach:
(found on https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/read-file-from-resources/)

```
  import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource
  import org.springframework.core.io.Resource

  Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("pdfResources/fonts/SFUIText-Medium.ttf") 
  String path = resource?.getPath()
```

Given the fact, that my app is called "filetest", the file is located on filetest/src/main/resources/pdfResources/fonts/SFUIText-Medium.ttf

This works with "grails run-app" and "grails war" as embedded runnable war file. Hope it helps, as it took me quite a while.